# How to modify parameter on other table with the relation 1-N in Laravel-Backpack?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

I have to update the image of a user profile at the time of the click on the save button.
To add the image using the following script:

```
$this->crud->addFields([
  [
   'name' => 'image',
   'value' => 'uploads/germany.jpg', //Is an example
   'label' => 'Image',
   'type' => 'browse'
  ]
]);
```

The problem is that I have my image table that is called `picture` whith the relation 1-N (1 [authors] - N [pictures]), how do I put my image in that table with Laravel-Backpack?

**TABLE authors** [1]

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',         //<-- PRIMARY KEY
    'name',
    'surname'
];
```

**TABLE pictures** [N]

```
 protected $fillable = [
    "id",
    "file",
    "nome",
    "tipo",
    "mime",
    "author_id"   //<-- FOREIGN KEY
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple pictures for one user (1-n relationship) you could use the [upload_multiple](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#upload_multiple) field type and use the mutator to store the entries in that separate table.